# Validating a chain of pointers

Tags: c++, syntax

To avoid an exception, one must check each pointer in a chain of pointers before making use of the inner pointer.

Is there a modern c++ syntax, or some easy way to replace the tedious:

```
if (pA && pA->pB && pA->pB->pC)
    pA->pB->pC->DoYerThing();
```

Into something like the following?

```
if(not_nullptrs(pA->pB->pC))
    pA->pB->pC->DoYerThing();
```

Comment: "To avoid an exception" - Dereferencing a `nullptr` or uninitialised pointer does *not* result in an exception. It results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I don't think I've ever needed to write code like that. What is your use case?

Comment: TL;DR: No, there isn't. Leaking out and having to dig through multiple levels of implementation details is code smell. I suggest you rethink your design.

Comment: Not using STL types (yet) or regular pointers. But it's pretty trivial to write your own simple `optional` for pointers with bind/map instructions (a-la Rust or almost any other language with similar type).

That way you could write `pA.bind([&](auto p){ return pB; }).bind(...)`, you get the idea.

See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0798r0.html

Comment: @DanM.: It is an EXACT duplicate of my question...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fixed version of Romeo's suggestion:

```
template <typename X0>
auto safe_chain(X0* x0)
{
    return x0;
}

template <typename X0, typename X1, typename... Xs>
auto safe_chain(X0* x0, X1 x1, Xs... xs)
{
    return x0
        ? safe_chain(x0->*x1, xs...)
        : nullptr;
}


// usage
struct C {
    void DoYerThing();
};
struct B {
    C* pC;
};
struct A {
    B* pB;
};

if(auto p = safe_chain(pA, &A::pB, &B::pC))
    p->DoYerThing();
```

This isn't exactly easy to read. `pA && pA->pB && pA->pB->pC` is just fine.

The idiomatic solution is usually to rely on references whenever possible, so that null pointer checks are limited to as few as possible. When a pointer is really needed, you should use a function (possibly a member function of `*pA`) to avoid duplicating the checks.

Comment: `safe_chain` can even be more generic and support smart pointers.

Comment: @Jarod42 perhaps... I don't see an example of that in the duplicate either. Care to show how you'd implement that?

Comment: `std::invoke` handles that, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks for fixing up my idea, didn't have time to test it out but I'm glad to see that I wasn't far off :P